# Spark filter weird behaviour with space character '\xa0'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, filtering

I have a Delta dataframe containing multiple columns and rows.

I did the following:

```
Delta.limit(1).select("IdEpisode").show()

+---------+
|IdEpisode|
+---------+
|  287 860|
+---------+
```

[image]

But then, when I do this:

```
Delta.filter("IdEpisode == '287 860'").show()
```

[image]

It returns 0 rows which is weird because we can clearly see the `Id` present in the dataframe.

I figured it was about the `' '` in the middle but I don't see why it would be a problem and how to fix it.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

```
Doing Delta.limit(1).select("IdEpisode").collect()[0][0]
```

returned: `'287\xa0860'`

And then doing:

```
Delta.filter("IdEpisode == '287\xa0860'").show()
```

returned the rows I've been looking for. Any explanation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This character is called [NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm). It's not a regular space that's why it is not matched with your filtering.

You can remove it using `regexp_replace` function before applying filter:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

Delta = spark.createDataFrame([('287\xa0860',)], ['IdEpisode'])

# replace NBSP character with normal space in column 
Delta = Delta.withColumn("IdEpisode", F.regexp_replace("IdEpisode", '[\\u00A0]', ' '))

Delta.filter("IdEpisode = '287 860'").show()
    
#+---------+
#|IdEpisode|
#+---------+
#|  287 860|
#+---------+
```

You can also clean your column by using the regex [`\p{Z}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to replace all kind of spaces with regular space:

> `\p{Z}` or `\p{Separator}`: any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.

```py
Delta = Delta.withColumn("IdEpisode", F.regexp_replace("IdEpisode", '\\p{Z}', ' '))
```

Comment: Is it an encoding problem ? How can I eliminate that special character

Comment: I know this answer is old but I still love you for it. I've been pulling my hair for HOURS until I found your answer!!!

Comment: Same thing happened to my colleague just now. Fiiiiiinally it works, thanks a lot for your answer!!